# Loading ViewController data into the model

Tags: iphone, ios, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller

I am working on an app which would collect data from six different View Controllers and then create a PDF summary of the data collected.  I know of two ways to aggregate the information from the multiple screens, but both seem cumbersome enough to make me thing there is a better way.

Option #1 - Core Data - Use `NSManagedObjects` then fetch, add and resave on the next View Controller then fetch... and resave... then fetch and resave.  Finally fetching everything to build the `PDF`.

Option #2 - Pass Data between View Controllers.  But it appears that I have to pass data from the current `VC` to the next one and then I will have to repass the same data to the following `VC` and so on.  Also quit laborious.

Is there an easier way to aggregate this data and pass it to the `PDF` when I call that class?

I am (obviously) relatively new to `iOS`.

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways of doing this, but one way is to define a singleton model object that all of the view controllers can access. For example, `Model.h` defines two properties, `text` and `array`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Model : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *text;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *array;

+ (instancetype)sharedModel;

@end
```

`Model.m` just implements the `sharedManager` method that allows the various controllers to get access to this shared model:

```
#import "Model.h"

@implementation Model

+ (instancetype)sharedModel
{
    static id sharedMyModel = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyModel = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyModel;
}

@end
```

Then, if a view controller wants to use this, just include a

```
#import "Model.h"
```

at the top, and then any view controller can access the model via:

```
Model *model = [Model sharedModel];
```

And now you can set or get the `text` and `array` properties to your heart's content. e.g.

```
model.text = @"Hello, World";
```

Obviously, just change the properties in `Model.h` to be whatever you want rather than my example of a string and an array.

Comment: +1 Perfect. It would sound nice if you change the `sharedManager` to `sharedModel` to go well with the name of class.

Comment: @Anupdas Good suggestion. This is one of my automated snippets in Xcode, so I just cut and paste, but of course that's a good idea. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks!  This did the trick and is very helpful.  Thanks also for your clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I built a project that was similar to this, where several view controllers added information to a shared singleton data object called assessedItem. I made a base view controller that all my view controllers inherited from that just had one property (assessedItem) with an overridden getter for that property:

```
-(AssessedItem *)assessedItem {
    if (! _assessedItem) {
        _assessedItem = [AssessedItem assessedItem];
    }
    return _assessedItem;
}
```

In the AssessedItem class, I had this one class method:

```
+ (id)assessedItem {
    static AssessedItem *assessedItem = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        assessedItem = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return assessedItem;
}
```

The AssessedItem class had a bunch of properties, and from any of the controllers, you could then set those properties just using normal dot syntax:

```
self.assessedItem.someProperty = @"whatever";
```